# Поиск подстрок в MYSQL

Tags: строки, like, mysql

Помогите организовать поиск записей из базы.
Использую MySQL. имеется 2.000.000 записей.
В каждой записи имеется поле состоящее из нескольких слов.
Идея поиска: пользователь вводит начальные символы подстроки. в ответ получает список найденных записей.
необходимо найти любое вхождение введенных символов в строке.
например: если ввели - 'QWE' то запись 'asd qwE asd' должен найти.
в LIKE '%string%' не используется индексация. Какие есть варианты решения?

Answer (score 1):

> Какие есть варианты решения?

Думаю оптимальный вариант — не делать этого в РСУБД. Используйте специализированные инструменты полнотекстового поиска. Например sphinx или lucene